# Transfer tool WHM

Tags: apache, transfer, whm

When using the transfer tool on WHM to move an account from one server to another does the old server website still remain live in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer process will not terminate your account from old server. You will have to update your domain nameserver so that your domain will be resolve to your new server.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer tool will help you to copy content, database from old server to new server. Once you copied all data then you need to point domain DNS to new server i.e IP and Nameserver and then website will start running from new server post DNS propagation.